# How do I check if time is positive or negative and compare it with fixed time

Tags: r, lubridate

Time is not a numeric datatype. So how do i check if

1. time is positive
2. compare time with some fixed time value

```
library(lubridate)

t = as_hms(Sys.time())

# question 1 - check if t is positive or negative

# question 2  - compare with time 11:23:01
```

Comment: How could you have negative time when checking the `Sys.time()`? Edit: and when you say compare, do you want the gap between the two dates or to know which is greater than the other?

Comment: @MonJeanJean, Sys.time() is just an example. I have time differences and I want to check how many time differences are positive.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Load the package `lubridate`. Then be sure your date have the `date` format. If not, use `lubridate::as_datetime(object)` function to convert it.

Then, all the "classic" functions will apply:

```
as_datetime(Sys.time()) > 0
[1] TRUE
```

And to compare two dates:

```
t <- as_datetime(Sys.time())
e <- as_datetime("2021-08-01")
> e > t
[1] TRUE
> e - t
Time difference of 30.38764 days
```